# Kendo grid batch edit notifications

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, datasource

I am using a kendo grid with batch editing style.
When editing (or creating) multiple records, the dataSource call update (or create) for each modified record. 
Is there a way to get notified when all of these requests are finished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a [`requestEnd`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#events-requestEnd) event that is fired when all requests are complete

From their docs:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  transport: {
    read: {
      url: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/products",
      dataType: "jsonp"
    }
  },
  requestEnd: function(e) {
    var response = e.response;
    var type = e.type;
    console.log(type); // displays "read"
    console.log(response.length); // displays "77"
  }
});
dataSource.fetch();
```

Note that this fires when all requests are made including initial loads and updates so you might want to check on which type request has completed:

```
function onGridRequestEnd(e) {
    if (e.type === "update") { //whatever... };
}
```